# How to make a buffered writer?

Tags: python, database, io, buffer, writer

So recently I took on as a personal project to make my very own DB in Python, mainly because I hate messing arround with most DBs and I needed something easy to setup, portable and simple to study large data sets.

I now find myself stuck on a problem, an efficient way to delete a line from the DB file (which is really just a text file). The way I found to do it is to write all of the content thats after the line before it, and then `truncate` the file (I take suggestions on better ways to do it). The problem arrives when I need to write the content after the line before it, because doing it all at once could possibly load millions of lines onto the RAM at once. The code follows:

```
ln = 11  # Line to be deleted
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    readlinef = f.readline
    for i in xrange(ln):
        line = readlinef()

    length, start = (len(line), f.tell()-len(line))
    f.seek(0, 2)
    chunk = f.tell() - start+length
    f.seek(start+length, 0)

    # How to make this buffered?
    data = f.read(chunk)
    f.seek(start, 0)
    f.write(data)
    f.truncate()
```

Right now thats reading all of that data at once, how would I make that last code block work in a buffered fashion? The start position would switch every time a new chunk of data is written before it, I was wondering what would be the most efficient and fast (execution time wise) way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

**edit**

I've decided to follow the advices submitted here, but just for curiosity's sake I found a way to read and write in chunks. It follows:

```
with open("test.txt", "r+") as f:
    readlinef = f.readline
    for i in xrange(ln):
        line = readlinef()

    start, length = (f.tell()-len(line), len(line))

    readf = f.read
    BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

    x = 0
    chunk = readf(BUFFER_SIZE)
    while chunk:
        f.seek(start, 0)
        f.write(chunk)
        start += BUFFER_SIZE
        f.seek(start+length+(x*BUFFER_SIZE), 0)
        chunk = readf(BUFFER_SIZE)

    f.truncate()
```

Comment: If efficiency is what you're after, you're using the worst possible data structure here. Removing line 2000 out of 5000 inherently means parsing 40% of the file and rewriting 60% of it, which is guaranteed to be slower than just about anything else you could do.

Comment: "make my very own DB" + "easy to setup, portable and simple to study large data sets" + " delete a line from the DB file (which is really just a text file)" = I am intrigued, sir.

Comment: Now seriously, why don't you just remove the record to be deleted from the index, and "vacuum" your page files, when your DBMS has time for it?

Comment: @abarnert I'm doing like this because I dont know of a better way to do it.

Comment: @Hyperboreus How would I do that?

Comment: @LuizBerti: Maybe you should read up a bit on how databases are implemented before trying to design your own. For example, if you create a file full of fixed-sized records, with references to a separate linked list of "varchar" strings, with deleted flags, you can remove a row just by jumping to the row's seek point, marking the row deleted, then jumping to each of its strings and marking them deleted. No need to count up 2000 newlines and then copy 2999 lines afterward.

Comment: @LuizBerti: Or, if you're going for a flat key-value database or a hierarchical database, you may want use a B+tree, which is just as easy to update as a flat file of records, but can be searched in logarithmic time instead of linear. Or, if you want full relational searching, you can create a flat file for the main records but then a B+tree for each index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this the same way that (effectively) `memmove` works: seek back and forth between the source range and the destination range:

```
count = (size+chunksize-1) // chunk size
for chunk in range(count):
    f.seek(start + chunk * chunksize + deleted_line_size, 0)
    buf = f.read(chunksize)
    f.seek(start + chunk * chunksize, 0)
    f.write(buf)
```

---

Using a temporary file and [`shutil`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) makes it a lot simpler—and, despite what you're expect, it may actually be faster. (There's twice as much writing, but a whole lot less seeking, and mostly block-aligned writing.) For example:

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile('w') as ftemp:
    shutil.copyfileobj(ftemp, f)
    ftemp.seek(0, 0)
    f.seek(start, 0)
    shutil.copyfileobj(f, ftemp)
f.truncate()
```

---

However, if your files are big enough to fit in your virtual memory space (which they probably are in 64-bit land, but may not be in 32-bit land), it may be simpler to just `mmap` the file and let the OS/libc take care of the work:

```
m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
m[start:end-deleted_line_size] = m[start+deleted_line_size:end]
m.close()
f.seek(end-deleted_line_size)
f.truncate()
```

Comment: I considered using a swap file but unless it's running on an SSD a regular hard drive would be very slow at accomplishing this. I will mark your answer as correct however I think I will go about implementing Hyperboreus's idea. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @LuizBerti: Don't just assume you know what "would be very slow". Worst-case, it's only 2x as slow as a "memory-buffered" solution—and, as I explained in the answer, it's likely to actually be faster. But you should always _test_ rather than guessing if it's important. And meanwhile, if performance matters at all to you, I already explained why the entire design is about as low-performance as you can get; a factor of 2 here and there is nothing compared to being O(N) when you could be constant or logarithmic.

Comment: @LuizBerti: Anyway, doing something like Hyperboreus's idea is a good idea. But again, you really should read a primer on database implementation, because there are a lot of important ideas that nobody could fit into an answer on SO.

Comment: @abarnert Thank you, but what I answered isn't *my* idea. No DBMS in the world could achieve its actual efficiency without much, Much, MUCH more sophisticated approaches than the rough cobbles I was able to present.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Sure. Obviously your answer isn't not enough to replace a whole course in database implementation strategies, but it's a better overview of a few key ideas than anyone has any right to expect from a SO answer, and hopefully it's enough to inspire the OP or a future reader to start reading up on the subject.

Answer (score 2):

Answering your question "How would I do that?" concerning indices and vacuum.

Disclaimer: This is a very simple example and does in no way compare to existing DBMS and I strongly advise against it.

Basic idea:

For each table in your DB, keep various files, some for your object ids (row ids, record ids) and some (page files) with the actual data. Let's suppose that each record is of variable length.

Each record has a table-unique OID. These are stored in the oid-files. Let's name the table "test" and the oid files "test.oidX". Each record in the oid file is of fixed length and each oid file is of fixed length.

Now if "test.oid1" reads:

```
0001:0001:0001:0015 #oid:pagefile:position:length
0002:0001:0016:0100
0004:0002:0001:0001
```

It means that record 1 is in page file 1, at position 1 and has length 15. Record 2 is in page file 1 at position 16 of length 100, etc.

Now when you want to delete a record, just touch the oid file. E.g. for deleting record 2, edit it to:

```
0001:0001:0001:0015
0000:0001:0016:0100 #0000 indicating empty cell
0004:0002:0001:0001
```

And don't even bother touching your page files.

This will create holes in your page files. Now you need to implement some "maintenance" routine which moves blocks in your page files around, etc, which could either run when requested by the user, or automatically when your DBMS has nothing else to do. Depending on which locking strategy you use, you might need to lock the concerned records or the whole table.

Also when you insert a new record, and you find a hole big enough, you can insert it there.

If your oid-files should also function as an index (slow inserts, fast queries), you will need to rebuild it (surely on insertion, maybe on deletion).

Operations on oid-files should be fast, as they are fixed-length and of fixed-length records.

This is just the very basic idea, not touching topics like search trees, hashing, etc, etc.